# JQuery - Adding a nested tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have these set of code from a helper:

```
$(document).ready(function(expanded) {
    var listItems = $('li.playerContainer');
    listItems.data("collapsed", true);
    $(listItems).click(function() {
        reset(this);
        var collapsed = $(this).data("collapsed");
        if (collapsed) {
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
                width: "450px",
                height: "500px"
            }).data("collapsed", false);
            $(this).children(".playerInfoR").addClass("rightAppear");
            $(this).children(".player_nameR").css({visibility:"hidden"});
            $(this).children(".closeR").addClass("rightAppear");
            $(this).children(".playerAchievesR").addClass("rightAppear");
        } else {
            $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
                width: "210px",
                height: "100px"
            }).data("collapsed", true);
            $(this).children(".playerInfoR").removeClass("rightAppear");
            $(this).children(".player_nameR").css({visibility:"visible"});
            $(this).children(".closeR").removeClass("rightAppear");
            $(this).children(".playerAchievesR").removeClass("rightAppear");
        };

        return false;
    });

    function reset(clicked) {
        $(listItems).not(clicked).stop(true, true).animate({
            width: "210px",
            height: "100px"
        }).data("collapsed", true);
        $(".playerInfoR").removeClass("rightAppear");
        $(".player_nameR").css({visibility:"visible"});
        $(".closeR").removeClass("rightAppear");
        $(".playerAchievesR").removeClass("rightAppear");
        return false;
    };

    $(".events").click(function(){

        $("events").load("http://www.yahoo.com");

    });

});
```

What it does is, between "li" items, click one to expand with the "width and height", and click again to reset it back to default.

now I want to add another button inside the "li" to click on and load a div in another page. Unfortunately, every time I click that button, it acted like I just only clicked onto the "li" itself, so it just gave the effect, and the button won't work even if I just want to click and get to another site. What can I do to make it clickable by itself.

Check on the Site please >>> [SiteTest](http://phatdesign.us/testProject/site1Test/)

Comment: A little bit of proper formatting goes a long way!

Comment: I spent five minutes looking at this question, and all I got was this lousy headache.

Comment: sorry guys, i'm a beginner ... learning you know .. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click on the button will bubble up to the `li` you need to call `event.stopPropagation()` if you want to prevent the li from expanding, or I think you could check and see if the element clicked was actually the `li` by checking `event.target`.

Halting event bubbling:

```
$('.events').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   // if you are using <a> tags for this you probably also
   // want to do e.preventDefault();

   $("#events").load("http://www.yahoo.com");
   return false;

});
```

Checking the element:

```
$(listItems).click(function(e) {
  if($(e.target).is(this)){
    // do your normal expand collapse stuff
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks so much it now can be clicked, but somehow it is now not load. please take a look at it http://phatdesign.us/testProject/site1Test/, click on the first one the left "Joan Camper"

Comment: its a tad buggy but it works for me. A couple things i do see though is that the size of your header make certain areas unclickable because it overlaps them if the item is at the top. Secondly it look slike youre pulling in the entire page (i can see title and link tags when the page loads... you might want to grab just the portion of the page youre loading. That could be interfering. Other than that you really should post a separate question on this since your initial question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

If I do get you correctly, than you can do something like this, which adds a eventhandler to the click event, and stops the event from bubbling

```
$('li.playerContainer #mybutton').click(function(event) {
    // do your stuff / loading page etc.

    // stop event from bubbling, so that your default li-handling will not take place
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: thank you, it is really weird now, please take a look at this

Comment: thank you, it is really weird now, please take a look at this http://phatdesign.us/testProject/site1Test/, it's just not load a page, am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: it works offline, but when I uploaded it, it don't work, please help